# Angular validation (can't reach controller if required fields are empty)

Tags: angularjs, validation, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement validation for a form using *Angular 1.1.1* and *Ionic*.

There are many "wallets" and the user needs to send a new "value" to each of the wallet. There's also a specified previous value of the wallet. The validation should check if all the input field are filled out and if the new value is bigger than previous.

My form (index.html):

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendValues(wallets)" ng-controller="valuesCtrl">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="wallet in wallets">
    <div class="col item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper item-text-wrap">
        <input name="wallet_{{wallet.id}}" type="number" ng-model="wallet.value" type="text" required/>
      </label>
      <span ng-show="myForm.wallet_{{item.id}}.$error.required">!!!</span>
    </div>            
    <div class="col item">{{ wallet.previous }}</div>    
  </div>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

It results in always showing "!!!" error for empty input even if the user haven't already submitted the form. I tried to use `$scope.myForm.submitted=true;` in the controller but the problem is **it reaches the controller only if all the fields are filled out**.

My controller (values.js):

```
'Use Strict';
angular.module('App')

.controller('valuesCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage, UserService, $state) {
    $scope.sendValues = function(wallets){
      debugger;
      ...
})
```

Can anyone help me to figure out why I can't see the debugger window if not all the fields are with info?
Can you suggest how to make a custom validation? (new value should be bigger than previous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It results in always showing "!!!" error for empty input even if the user haven't already submitted the form?

Your `ng-show` should be

```
ng-show="myForm.$submitted==true && myForm.wallet_{{item.id}}.$error.required"
```

and form should be have `novalidate` attribute if you want custom validation

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="sendValues(wallets)" novalidate>
```

**otherwise it will do default html validation**

> I tried to use $scope.myForm.submitted=true; in the controller but the problem is it reaches the controller only if all the fields are filled out

Its because `ng-submit` will validate for true condition`($valid==true)` for every form control element .

If it is filled and valid data then only form `$valid` flag is set to `true` otherwise not.In case `$valid==true`,you will able to submit the form and function in controller get fired

you can use

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="sendValues(wallets)" value="Save" />
```

if you want to submit the form without validation and want to do validation in controller

You can read more from [angular#form](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: I cannot set ```myForm.$submitted==true``` in the controller when all the fields are not present

Comment: If you want then dont use `ng-submit`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about 'novalidate'.